# Data Warehouse Design for People not Products

Tags: database-design, data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling, fact

I understand the star schema of facts and dimensions is recommended for products, orders and that style of data.

Is there a recommended way to `model facts about people` from monthly reports e.g tracking progress over time where the `person` may change state `(progressing, Absence, Completed, NewPerson)` between months and also that person would be associated with a number of `mentors` which could also change between reports.

- Would I have a `dimension` table for each `state` and each `mentor
  role` with the date the fact was true recorded.
- Do I need 2 fact tables? 1 for the person and another for the mentors?
- How does other data fit in like expected end date

Comment: hi Mobcdi .. A quick question before I post an answer.. What would be a business activity that you might be trying to track.. For eg: Would it be something like : A person's career progression over a period of time??

Comment: That's a good example. Person may change departments, have different managers or leave the company. Also managers could leave as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the example that we discussed in the comments section, you could have the following data marts.

***Fact Table:***

A fact table to record the activity of people moving(I just picked a name)
**Fact_People_Move**

Please consider how you would like to record the 'business activity' and then decide up on whether it is a Transactional Fact or a Snapshot Fact.

More on different Fact tables from Kimball:
http://www.kimballgroup.com/2008/11/fact-tables/

***Dimension tables:***

A table to hold employee details:
Dim_Employee
This table could role play as Employee and Mentors, as Mentors could be Employees themselves.

A table to hold dates:
Dim_Date

A table to hold Addresses (only if you would like to record addresses):
Dim_Address

A table to hold the divisions/sections of the organisation:
Dim_Division

There could be so many other dims and may be other facts(if you want to record more business activities).

Comment: When you talk about the dates dimension table. Do you mean dates when a fact (promotion, demotion, leaving) took place or something else

Comment: @mobcdi you normally generate a universal date dimension, there is plenty on that matter around the Internet. You store it as a reference within the fact table to some precision. Books advise to store a timestamp for exact time of when a fact took place within the fact table itself.

Comment: Thanks Kamil .. Hi Mobcdi.. Yes..any kind of dates that you would like to record.

Comment: One row per date, which describes everything about a date. Then your facts refer to the date that applies to them. This is not just the dates that the facts use- its the other dates too.